# Have MVC look for a specific view by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Standard MVC pattern for ControllerC/ActionA when controller code just states return View() is to look for ControllerC/ActionA.cshtml. I would like make it so if such view does not exist, it looks for some default view like Shared/Default.cshtml. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about MVC 5, but you could create custom class from RazorViewEngine.

```
public class MyFallbackLocationViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyFallbackLocationViewEngine()
    {
        // Keep default locations and add our own fallback view
        List<string> newLocations = new List<string>(ViewLocationFormats);
        newLocations.Add("~/Views/Shared/Default.cshtml");
        this.ViewLocationFormats = newLocations.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And add it to your Application_Start:

```
// Clear default engines and add only yours
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyFallbackLocationViewEngine());
```

You could customize your ViewEngine as much as you lilke and override other methods

Comment: Thanks, I will test this and report back as soon as I can